# How do you sort fields randomly in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Im trying to list my fields in a random order. I dont see any interface means of doing it and I've triend creaiting actions:

```
def randomsort (modeladmin, request, queryset)
     queryset.order_by('?')
```

and

```
 def randomsort (modeladmin, request, queryset)
      queryset.order_by('?order')  where order is the name of my order field
```

None of these work, any ideas?

Comment: `order_by('?')` is correct solution. Can you show us your query set?

Answer (score 0):

`order_by()` does not manipulate the original queryset, it just shuffles the values and returns a new queryset. For example:

```
myqueryset.order_by('?')
```

Doesn't do anything. However:

```
myqueryset = myqueryset.order_by('?')
```

Does what you're looking for. Chances are, you aren't calling the randomsort properly, since you aren't returning anything. The solution is to modify your function:

```
def randomsort (modeladmin, request, queryset)
    return queryset.order_by('?')  #where order is the name of my order field
```

And then call it appropriately:

```
myqueryset = randomsort(modeladmin, request, queryset)
```